# Tcl: Persistent increment inside a list

Tags: list, tcl, increment

I am trying to set-up multiple incr's for each entry in a list. I thought that I could assign an integer to each list entry...

```
set list { 
      {/run      00}
      {/run/shm  00}
      {/boot     00}
}
```

and use the following code as part of a foreach loop to increment the value...

```
lset list 1 [expr {[lindex $list 1] + 1}]
```

What I am finding is that the value increments correctly but when the code executes a second and third time the value has reset to 00, so it never increases past 1 on each pass.

If I set up a basic increment for a standard variable as part of the code..

```
set counter 00
incr counter
```

it quite happily increments on each run of the code and the counter increases by 1 until I break the code.

Any advise or help in getting this working would be much appreciated. I am definitely not a tcl expert so if I am trying to accomplish this the wrong way please let me know. :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that doing *this:*

```
for {set idx 0} {$idx < [llength $list]} {incr idx} {
    lset list $idx 1 [expr {[lindex $list $idx 1] + 1}]
}
```

would increment every numeric value in that list, which is what I believe you want to do. However, doing *this:*

```
foreach pair $list {
    lset pair 1 [expr {[lindex $pair 1] + 1}]
}
```

will *not* work. Tcl conceptually copies the sublist-items out of the main list in `foreach` so that the changes to the `pair`s aren't reflected back. Also, conceptually Tcl also copies the value to hand to `foreach` in the first place. Of course, these copies are not actually real, as that would be very expensive! Instead Tcl uses shared references with copy-on-write-to-shared semantics, a system that works very well given that we can check the sharing status very cheaply (which is enabled by Tcl's threading model; values are *never* shared between threads, so sharing-state decisions can be lock-free and local).

A consequence of this is that Tcl explicitly rejects weird at-a-distance state changes of the kinds that cause weird bugs sometimes in languages with different semantics. If you're changing something, it'd better be a variable (as those are the main mutable things) and you'll have it right there in front of you when you do the change.

Comment: A consequence of this is that the `foreach` won't see any changes made to the list it is iterating over from inside its body: that's actually not the same list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Donal, that did the trick. Using `for` instead of `foreach` updated the increments for each list entry and they were persistent throughout the iterations of the code. Thanks a lot for the in-depth info in regards to the workings of `foreach`. I would never have guessed that would have been my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your data structure slightly to flatten it out instead of using a list of pairs, it becomes usable as a dict. And there's a [`dict incr`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm#M14) command:

> This adds the given increment value (an integer that defaults to 1 if not specified) to the value that the given key maps to in the dictionary value contained in the given variable, writing the resulting dictionary value back to that variable. Non-existent keys are treated as if they map to 0. It is an error to increment a value for an existing key if that value is not an integer. The updated dictionary value is returned.

Example usage:

```
% set list {/run 0 /run/shm 0 /boot 0}
/run 0 /run/shm 0 /boot 0
% dict incr list /boot
/run 0 /run/shm 0 /boot 1
% puts $list
/run 0 /run/shm 0 /boot 1
```

If you want to do this in a command, you have to pass by name and use [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) so the changes are made in the right stack frame:

```
% proc demo {fstab_} {
    upvar 1 $fstab_ fstab
    dict incr fstab /run
  }
% demo list
/run 1 /run/shm 0 /boot 1
% puts $list
/run 1 /run/shm 0 /boot 1
```

And to update every value:

```
% foreach dir [dict keys $list] { dict incr list $dir }
% puts $list
/run 2 /run/shm 1 /boot 2
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, it's good to know that there are multiple ways to skin that cat :) Very handy.